# Is there a temperate climate perennial succulent adapted to wet root conditions?

Tags: plant-recommendations, perennials, succulents

Is there a succulent plant that can grow in wet/swampy conditions?

I've never seen it, but I think it would be an interesting change from the usual sedgy/grassy looking swamp plants that grow around here.

Comment: Have you tried sempervivum tectorum? I'm not saying they'll work, but they are known as liveforever. I'm just curious. They don't seem to mind lots of water so far (after a little while inside in a container of what is essentially thick mud, after growing a few roots in a glass of water). I'm thinking they're adaptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virginia glasswort ([Sarcornia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcocornia)), is a perennial succulent that will tolerate wet root conditions. However as it is a [halophyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halophyte) adapted for life in salt marshes, its suitability for landscaping purposes is limited.

Most of the aquatic/wetland succulents I could find info on were from saline environments, which makes sense when you think about it.

[Succulence](http://www.desertmuseum.org/programs/succulents_adaptation.php) is an adaptation to water scarce environments like deserts. The high salinity in salt marshes or high salt soils effectively impose water scarcity on resident plants, so it isn't surprising to see succulence in these environments.

In freshwater systems and wet soils, however, water is not scarce, so plants don't need to develop such adaptations. Rather they need to [adapt](http://ci.coastal.edu/~sgilman/778Plants.htm) to deal with excess water.

That said, there is this wetland plant called [Cursed Crowfoot](http://www.illinoiswildflowers.info/wetland/plants/cursed_crowfoot.htm) which may not technically be a succulent, but is described as having succulent foliage. But this is probably not a plant you want to mess around with "Because the succulent foliage contains a strong blistering agent..."